# Generating 229 sum numbers out of 3660

Tags: packing

I have 3660 single values, which I need to sum up to 229.
For the 229 target values exist constraints. 
The task is comparable with distributing 3660 balls to 229 boxes and considering the sum of the number on the balls.
My task is to minimize the deviation of all generated sums to the constraints.

First research has given me a hint to the packing problem (especially the bin packing problem) but I honestly have no idea how to solve this particular problem without simulating all cases (here 229^3660).

Comment: a small example would be nice, with smaller numbers than 229 and 3660

Comment: So what code have you tried so far?

Comment: For example I have the numbers from 1 to 10 and want to distribute them to 2 boxes. For box 1 I have the constraint that it's sum should ideally be 40 and for box 2 the information the sum should be 16. Now the task is to distribute the numbers to the boxes so that the error of the all boxes (here 2) is minimized.

Comment: my current approach is the following code but I highly doubt it is the best one

Comment: sorting the values
distributing the highest values to the boxes so that the highest gap to a constraint becomes lower